# PNG alpha weirdness Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, reflection

[image]Hey guys, my eevee render is sorta double-reflecting my PNG sequence. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Can you post either this file, or one like it (that exhibits the issue) using your setup? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/